# Jquery UI slider attach label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a modal, that shows up at certain times and I have two sliders on it, which should show some values. Here's the code:

```
div#averageAnswerModal.modal.fade.custom-modal(tabindex="-1", role="dialog", aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true")
div.modal-content
    div.modal-body(style='text-align: center;')
        h2 Your neighbor's answers average was:
        div
            div#noAvg Your neighbors didn't give any anwer
            div#avgSlider
            span#avgLabel
        h2 Your answer was:
        div
            dvi#notAnswered You didn't give anwer
            div#yourSlider
            span#yourLabel
```

I have this code to set up the sldiers

```
initializeModal = function() {
        var positionLabel = function(label, slider, val) {
            $(label).html(val).position({
                my: 'center top',
                at: 'center bottom',
                of: $(slider + ' > .ui-slider-handle')
            })
        }

        myModal = $('#averageAnswerModal').modal({
            show: false,
            keybord: false
        })

        $("#avgSlider").slider({
            max: 100,
            disabled: true,
            change: function(event, ui) {
                positionLabel('#avgLabel', "#avgSlider", ui.value)
            }
        })

        $("#yourSlider").slider({
            max: 100,
            disabled: true,
            change: function(event, ui) {
                positionLabel('#yourLabel', "#yourSlider", ui.value)
            }
        })
    }
```

And this code fires them up:

```
createSplashSliders = function(avg, your) {
    myModal.modal('show')
    if (avg === -1) {
        $("#noAvg").show()
        $("#avgSlider").hide()
        $('#avgLabel').hide()
    } else {
        $("#noAvg").hide()
        $("#avgSlider").show()
        $('#avgLabel').show()
        $("#avgSlider").slider('value', avg)
    }

    if (your === -1) {
        $("#notAnswered").show()
        $("#yourSlider").hide()
        $('#yourLabel').hide()
    } else {
        $("#notAnswered").hide()
        $("#yourSlider").show()
        $('#yourLabel').show()
        $("#yourSlider").slider('value', your)
    }
}
```

The sliders show up correctly and I wanted to attach the selected value below the handle. It attaches the values like 2 lines below and if I use the page repeatedly the span just moves down with a line every time the modal shows up. When I stop the code with debugger in `positionLabel` and just copy+paste the same code the label gets attached to the right place.

I've been stuck with this problem for half a day and I still cannot figure out what's wrong.

**UPDATE**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1518/). If you put a debugger in the `positionLabel` and just step through it will position the labels correctly. So somewhere I have a timing issue, just don't know where or why.

Comment: Fiddle please buddy...

Answer (score 0):

If I add a timeout to

```
        var positionLabel = function(label, slider, val) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(label).html(val).position({
                    my: 'center top',
                    at: 'center bottom',
                    of: $(slider + ' > .ui-slider-handle')
                })
            }, 200);
        }
```

This works... but not with timeout of `5`. Why do I need this timeout?